# jQuery Cycle - to keep track of what element is being shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

Using the jQuery Cycle plugin, the following code allows user to browse the photos/:

```
$('#slideShow').cycle({ 
    fx:     'shuffle',
    shuffle: { 
      top:  -230, 
      left:  230 
    }, 
    speed:  300, 
    next:   '#slideShow', 
    timeout: 0 
});
```

Can anyone suggest if there is a way to keep track which image is being shown at the moment?

Let's say, there are 5 images, I want to be able to show caption of each picture. So, I have to know which image is being clicked in order to show the correct caption.

Comment: Pretty sure this is in the API docs...

Comment: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/caption.html

Comment: @Tieson T. Forgive me for not being able to find the API docs around the website,...Either the website is not user friendly enough or I posses a bad researching/finding skill..Could you send me the link where it contains the API docs ???

Comment: Well, [http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) contains every option available. Other than that, just spend some time looking at the various demos. You can easily view the source of every demo to see how the effect was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following link shows the example of caption used for fancybox:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/caption.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `after` event.

```
after: function() {
    // this  contains the current image
    // $(this) makes a jQuery object
}
```